# In the card game "War", what happens when a player plays their final card in a War?

Tags: war

For the card game [War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_%28card_game%29), what happens when a player plays their last card as part of the war?

1. When their last card is the first card of the war (face up), before the three face down cards are dealt
2. When their last card is one of the three face down cards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

The linked Wikipedia article has this to say:

> Most descriptions of War are unclear about what happens if a player
>   runs out of cards during a war. In some variants, that player
>   immediately loses. In others, the player may play the last card in
>   their deck as their face-up card for the remainder of the war.

Answer (score -4):

Also, in some variants the other opponents must take the needed cards from the *top* of their hand and give it to the other player for them to use in the **same order**.